# Изменить координаты точек полигона

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть полигон, у которого не указан массив точек. Требуется в процессе работы эти точки указать.
Попробовал использовать setCoordinates(), но она видимо только для окружности. Ничего похожего для полигона так и не смог найти.
Если ли какие-нибудь способы указать массив точек на полигоне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
myGeoObject.geometry.setCoordinates([[
[55.75, 37.80],
[55.80, 37.90],
[55.70, 37.80]
]]);
```